# Possible to Look Up Groups in Pytables through Dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary, hdf5, pytables

I was wondering if its possible to store some kind of dictionary within pytables that could map an id to an instance of a group? Currently, I am trying to separate my data within groups; however, the lookup time to find these groups (through getNode method) takes a very long time.

Instead of when opening a file to read and having to invoke getNode to search the tree to find the group, I want to be able to open a dictionary within the file that allows me to lookup the group/table instance. Is this a possibility?

Comment: Have you read http://pytables.github.com/usersguide/optimization.html?  Also, do you have the Pro version?  Pro has OPSI that might help you out.

Comment: Yeah, the only problem though is that my primary id, which is int64, is not able to be indexed by OPSI.